# How to make ffmpegthumbnailer work on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ffmpeg, carrierwave, ffmpegthumbnailer

I use "carrierwave" to upload and play video on website. It requires ffmpeg and ffmpegthumbnailer so I also set them up. Everything work well on local but then it fails when I try to repeat on Heroku.

The error messages are shown below:

```
File Failed to thumbnail with ffmpegthumbnailer. Check ffmpegthumbnailer install and verify video is not corrupt. Original error: No such file or directory - ffmpegthumbnailer
```

It seems the ffmpeg work well but the ffmpegthumbnailer have some problem because I got exactly the same error when I installed ffmpeg and forgot to install ffmpegthumbnailer on local. This problem on local was solved when I finished installed ffmpegthumbnailer.

I also ran command `heroku run "ffmpegthumbnailer -version"` to verify and I got `bash: ffmpegthumbnailer: command not found`

I have tried the solution shown in this link: [akomic/heroku-buildpack-ffmpegthumbnailer](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/akomic/heroku-buildpack-ffmpegthumbnailer) but it doesn't work.

Is there any solution I can try? Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this one https://gist.github.com/ttseng/7682321? It's well documented and I believe it will help.